# .NET Core and React app - Loading main.chunk.js multiple times

Tags: reactjs, azure, caching, .net-core

I have a .NET Core 3.1 app supporting an API, and a React app which acts as an admin portal. This React app was generated using the boilerplate from .NET core.

I was checking the networks calls and every time the user logs in or out, there's a Javascript file called. It takes 2-3 seconds to load this file every time.

In the image below, there are 3 redirects when the user logs out, and the file gets called 3 times.

[image]

The .NET Core app is hosted inside Azure.

Is there a way to cache this file, either using an Azure service or declaring a cache somehow?

Comment: I would like to understand, why in the first place you need to download it 3 times. what is causing this to download it 3 times. This is not optimal.

Comment: @ahmed I’m not doing that. It’s the boilerplate that came with .NET Core that’s doing this. I also think it’s a waste.

Comment: I see. Can you check in your inspector who is initiating this call to min.*.js. I am not aware of this .NET framework but curious that is there a configuration that can fix this up.